# How to force a Custom Layout to accept View content in @ViewBuilder

Tags: swift, swiftui

I've created a custom layout and since they are available on iOS >=16 I would like to use a @ViewBuilder to hide it with its fallback code:

So instead of having this in my View:

```
if #available(iOS 16, *) {
    CustomLayout() {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
} else {
    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}
```

I would like to hide it behind:

```
struct ProportionalView<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            CustomLayout() { content } //  Here is what's wrong
        } else {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, content: content)
        }
    }
}


//Then use it in the View as:
ProportionalView {
    Text("Hello, World!")
}
```

Pretty standard SwiftUI practic. But it looks like the Custom Layout doesn't work this way. While it accepts type `View` in SwiftUI View code, it doesn't accept it here and gives an error: `"Type '() -> Content' cannot conform to 'View'"`. And if I wrap it in `Group { }` an error `No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'`

Is there a way to force Custom Layout accept a View in @ViewBuilder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `content` like this:

```
@ViewBuilder var content: () -> Content
```

which means it is a function. To get a `View`, you have to actually call the function:

```
CustomLayout() { content() }
                     // ^^ add parens to call the function
```

But for the code you posted, it's probably better to change `content` to **not** be a function, as it will be slightly more efficient due to not storing an escaping closure on the heap:

```
struct ProportionalView<Content: View>: View {
    @ViewBuilder var content: Content
                          //  ^^^^^^^ change type

    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
            CustomLayout() { content }
        } else {
            VStack(
                alignment: .leading,
                content: { content }
                      // ^^^^^^^^^^^ wrap this use in a function
            )                                     
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant! I have the same code for switching between NavigationStack and older NavigationView. Do you recommend switching it to 'Content as a View' too, to be slightly more efficient?

Comment: It depends on whether `NavigationStack` and `NavigationView` take escaping arguments. If they do, then it doesn’t matter. If they don’t, then it’s better that you don’t either.